# Server Internal Error 500 on CakePHP 2.0

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, internal-server-error

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 for my website frameworks, I located my cakephp files on server but i have some problems, named Server Internal Error 500, I don't know what i supposed to do, the other pages is working well, but some pages is encountered a 500 server internal error, I've checked the controller, view, model, and they said is no error detected, but the firebug says, the view is missing, this is my `.htaccess` file

public_html/cakephp/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /~magang/smkn1pst/
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

public_html/cakephp/app

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
        RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
   </IfModule>
```

public_html/cakephp/app/webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /~magang/smkn1pst/
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I already following steps, by adding `/` ex: app/webroot/ to /app/webroot/ and  webroot/ to  /webroot/ but still not works for me, i need to steps up to the next project, but this problem is bugging my day.

Answer (score 2):

You are using mod_userdir, when using that indeed you need the RewriteBase, as mod_rewrite removes the ~ charachter

```
RewriteBase /~magang/smkn1pst
```

in all 3 .htaccess files should work, as it does for me

Currently one of your files is missing this line

Comment: my url server is [link](http://dev.mediainfo.co.id/~magang/smkn1pst/) and nothing missing, the error is here [link](http://dev.mediainfo.co.id/~magang/smkn1pst/students/view) and here [link](http://dev.mediainfo.co.id/~magang/smkn1pst/absences/view) 
the problems is when you click link 
user : admin
pass : admin

i need u're help bro.

Answer (score 0):

This should help fix your error.

http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/getting_http_1_0_500_internal_server_error_in_my_cakephp_website

Comment: thanks for you're answers, 
i've already do that tutorial, but still not works..
thanks for drop here..

Comment: i'm not sure that video could be a solution bro. :D

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure please try

```
RewriteBase /smkn1pst/
```

Comment: still cannot works, cause my url is http://dev.mediainfo.co.id/~magang/smkn1pst/.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (static files were redirected properly with the correct RewriteBase in the root htaccess).

It turned out (after 4 hours of debugging .htaccess) that my FTP client had skipped the app/tmp/ directory because of a rule I added myself.

That also yielded a 500 error.

Comment: @Divyanshu Uploaded app/tmp and fixed permissions.

Comment: Thats weired... I already have tmp folder and proper permissions..
I fixed it by adding a '/' before  index.php in webroot/.htaccess.